# Update http_proxy environment variable in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: http, proxy, environment-variables, http-proxy

I just updated my proxy username's password and now I want to update the http_proxy environment variable.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal and type this

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
export http_proxy
```

Replace User, password, host and port to your proxy setting and you are good to go :)

Comment: Put this in your bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

[MisterX's answer](https://superuser.com/a/523018/513819) is correct:

> ```
> http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/
> export http_proxy
> ```

But don't forget to convert your characters if they are special seen
[here](https://serverfault.com/a/479862/957684).

URL Escape Codes table

| Char | Esc Code |
| --- | --- |
| SPACE | %20 |
| < | %3C |
| > | %3E |
| # | %23 |
| % | %25 |
| { | %7B |
| } | %7D |
|  |  |
| \ | %5C |
| ^ | %5E |
| ~ | %7E |
| [ | %5B |
| ] | %5D |
| ` | %60 |
| ; | %3B |
| / | %2F |
| ? | %3F |
| : | %3A |
| @ | %40 |
| = | %3D |
| & | %26 |
| $ | %24 |

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=url+escaping&ia=answer&iax=answer